# ranking lowest number excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need column A to rank lowest 6 times put into column H. If the time is 0 column A should be blank. If it says DQ in column H, column A can be blank or state DQ. I'm having issues with it returning a 'false' instead of placing. Other formulas I've tried have given me the '#NUM' error.

My formulas are below:

Column A:

=IF(H4=0," ",IF(H4="DQ","DQ",IF(H4=0,"",IF(H4=SMALL(H4:H34,1),"1",IF(H4=SMALL(H4:H34,2),"2",IF(H4=SMALL(H4:H34,3),"3",IF(H4=SMALL(H4:H34,4),"4",IF(H4=SMALL(H4:H34,5),"5",IF(H4=SMALL(H4:H34,6),"6",IF(H4="DQ",""))))))))))

Column H: 
=IF(G4="DQ","DQ",IF(E4<>0, E4+G4, 0))

[image]

Comment: In the example you are checking SMALL(H4:H34). If the formula is copied down to the next cell it becomes SMALL(H5:H35). Is that what you want? Or do you want a constant range to be looked at? If so, you would want something like SMALL($H:$3, $H$33).

Comment: Constant range...thanks I'll add that. Any ideas on the placing issues?

Comment: Yes. You have a complicated If statement in col A. That is OK. try rebuilding it step by step. Make sure it is giving you what you expect at each step of the way. Example: IF(H4=0," ","Something"). If that statement works, Put the next IF in place of "Something".